# ¿cómo puedo acceder a un arreglo que está dentro de otro arreglo? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Suponiendo que tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
var b = [30, 35]
var a = [4, 9, 16, 25, 29, b];
```

¿cómo podría acceder a el arreglo b, para listar todos sus valores?

Comment: Un arreglo es como cualquier otro valor, el modo de acceder al valor de un array es el mismo independientemente del tipo de dato. solo indica la posición segun el orden en el que introduces los elementos de izquierda a derecha contando desde 0, haciendo uso de los [ ], los arreglos también son un objeto en realidad no son un tipo de dato aparte. debes acceder con la notación de corchetes [posición] y no con un "." por que los nombres de las propiedades son caracteres numéricos y no un identificador alfanumérico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que te funcione es un ejemplo básico.

```js
var b = [30, 35]
var a = [4, 9, 16, 25, 29, b];
var posicion = a.indexOf(b);
console.log('b dentro de a', a[posicion]);
```

Comment: Gracias bro, sí funciona!